# Como inverter as posições

Tags: java, array

Estou fazendo um trabalho de LFA (linguagens formais e autômatos), que reconhece linguagens GLUD só que agora eu gostaria de fazer ele reconhecer linguagens GLUE, que basicamente seria apenas mudas a posição da letra maiúscula ( estadoDestino ).

PS: o programa recebe um arquivo gramatica.gr aonde contem as regras de transição.

Ex:
GLUD
Gram = ({S, A, B}, {a, b}, 
{
    S -> aA, 
    A -> bB, 
    A -> λ,
    B -> aA,
    },
S)

Ex: GLUE Gram = ({S, A, B}, {a, b}, { S -> Aa, A -> Bb, A -> λ, B -> Aa, }, S)

A única diferença é a posição do estadoDestino e estadoAtual.

O método que cuida disso é o setRules, a principio tentei apenas mudar o os valores dos substring, para trocar as posições dos valores que ela pega. 
Em vez de (0,1) mudei para (1,0) só que mesmo assim continua dando erro... n sei mais oq mudar para conseguir inverter os valores...

Programa Rodando:

[image: Programa rodando.]

Atualmente quando tento usar GLUE

[image: Erro Quando tendo adicionar uma GLUE]

> Main.java

```
package verificador;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Verificador {

    private final ArrayList<State> states;
    private final ArrayList<String> alphabet;
    private final ArrayList<Rule> rules;
    private State inicial;

    public Verificador() {
        states = new ArrayList<>();
        alphabet = new ArrayList<>();
        rules = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void setStates(String states) {
        states = states.replaceAll("\\{|\\}", ""); // Tira {}
        for (String e : states.split(",")) {
            this.states.add(new State(e));
        }
        this.states.add(new State("DEFAULT", true));
    }

    public State getStateByName(String name) {
        for (State e : states) {
            if (e.getName().equals(name)) {
                return e;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void setAlphabet(String alphabet) {
        alphabet = alphabet.replaceAll("\\{|\\}", ""); // Tira {}
        this.alphabet.addAll(Arrays.asList(alphabet.split(",")));
        this.alphabet.add("#");
        this.alphabet.add("λ");
    }

    public boolean checkLetter(String letter) {
        for (String l : alphabet) {
            if (l.equals(letter)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void setRules(String regras) throws Exception {
        regras = regras.replaceAll("\\{|\\}", ""); // Tira {}
        for (String regra : regras.split(",")) {
            String[] r = regra.split("->");
            if (r.length != 2) {
                throw new Exception("Regra mal formatada");
            }
            State estadoAtual = getStateByName(r[0]);
            if (estadoAtual == null) {
                throw new Exception("Regra mal formatada - Estado invalido1:" + r[0]);
            }
            try {
                for (String transicao : r[1].split("\\|")) {
                    State estadoDestino;
                    String letter = transicao.substring(0,1);
                    if(!checkLetter(letter)){
                        throw new Exception("Regra mal formata - Caracter invalido: " + transicao.substring(0,1));
                    }
                    if (transicao.substring(1).equals("")) {
                        estadoDestino = getStateByName("DEFAULT");
                    } else {
                        estadoDestino = getStateByName(transicao.substring(1));
                        if (estadoDestino == null) {
                            throw new Exception("Regra mal formatada - Estado invalido:" + transicao.substring(1));
                        }
                    }
                    this.rules.add(new Rule(letter, estadoAtual, estadoDestino));
                }
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                throw new Exception("Regra mal formatada");
            }
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<Rule> getPossibleRules(State estado, String elemento) {
        ArrayList<Rule> regras = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Rule r : this.rules) {
            if (r.getState() == estado && r.getElement().equals(elemento)) {
                regras.add(r);
            }
        }
        return regras;
    }

    public void setInicial(String inicial) throws Exception {
        State estado = getStateByName(inicial);
        if (estado == null) {
            throw new Exception("Estado inicial invalido");
        }
        this.inicial = estado;
    }

    // ({A,B,C}; {a,b,c}; A -> aB | bA | cA | λ, B -> aB | bC | cA | λ, C -> aB | bA | λ; A)
    public void readGrammar(String gramatica) throws Exception {
        gramatica = gramatica.replaceAll("\\(|\\)|\\s+|\\n", ""); // Tira parentesis e espaços

        if(gramatica.contains("=")){ // Tira o nome da gramatica do inicio
            gramatica = gramatica.split("=")[1];
        }
        gramatica = gramatica.replaceAll("\\},", "\\};"); // Substitui a , por ;
        String[] g = gramatica.split(";"); // Quebra partes da gramatica
        if (g.length != 4) {
            throw new Exception("Gramatica mal formatada");
        }
        setStates(g[0]);
        setAlphabet(g[1]);
        setRules(g[2]);
        setInicial(g[3]);
    }

  public void printRules() {
        for (Rule r : rules) {
            System.out.println(r.toString());
        }
    }

  boolean checkWord(String palavra) {
        System.out.format("%-10s %-10s\n", "Palavra", "Estado");
        System.out.format("%-10s %-10s\n", palavra, inicial);
        return checkWord(palavra, inicial);
    }

    boolean checkWord(String palavra, State estadoAtual) {
        System.out.format("%-10s %-10s\n", palavra, estadoAtual);
        if (palavra.isEmpty() && estadoAtual.getIsFinal()) { // terminou a palavra
            return true;
        } else if (palavra.isEmpty()) {
            return false;
        }
        ArrayList<Rule> possiveisRegras = getPossibleRules(estadoAtual, String.valueOf(palavra.charAt(0)));
        for (Rule r : possiveisRegras) {
            if (checkWord(palavra.substring(1), r.getDestiny())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

> Rule.java

```
package verificador;

public class Rule {
    private String element;
    private State state;
    private State destiny;

    public Rule(String element, State state, State destiny){
        this.element = element;
        this.state = state;
        this.destiny = destiny;
        if(element.equals("#") || element.equals("λ")){
            this.state.setIsFinal(true);
        }
    }

    public String getElement() {
        return element;
    }

    public void setElement(String element) {
        this.element = element;
    }

    public State getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(State state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public State getDestiny() {
        return destiny;
    }

    public void setDestiny(State destiny) {
        this.destiny = destiny;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return state + " -> " + element + destiny;
    }
}
```

> State.java

```
package verificador;

public class State {
    private String name;
    private boolean isFinal;

    public State(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public State(String name, boolean isFinal){
        this.name = name;
        this.isFinal = isFinal;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public boolean getIsFinal() {
        return isFinal;
    }

    public void setIsFinal(boolean isFinal) {
        this.isFinal = isFinal;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        if(name.equals("DEFAULT")){
            return "";
        }
        return name;
    }

}
```

> Verificador.java
>   (Local aonde cuida disso, método responsável setRules();

```
package verificador;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Verificador {

    private final ArrayList<State> states;
    private final ArrayList<String> alphabet;
    private final ArrayList<Rule> rules;
    private State inicial;

    public Verificador() {
        states = new ArrayList<>();
        alphabet = new ArrayList<>();
        rules = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void setStates(String states) {
        states = states.replaceAll("\\{|\\}", ""); // Tira {}
        for (String e : states.split(",")) {
            this.states.add(new State(e));
        }
        this.states.add(new State("DEFAULT", true));
    }

    public State getStateByName(String name) {
        for (State e : states) {
            if (e.getName().equals(name)) {
                return e;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void setAlphabet(String alphabet) {
        alphabet = alphabet.replaceAll("\\{|\\}", ""); // Tira {}
        this.alphabet.addAll(Arrays.asList(alphabet.split(",")));
        this.alphabet.add("#");
        this.alphabet.add("λ");
    }

    public boolean checkLetter(String letter) {
        for (String l : alphabet) {
            if (l.equals(letter)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void setRules(String regras) throws Exception {
        regras = regras.replaceAll("\\{|\\}", ""); // Tira {}
        for (String regra : regras.split(",")) {
            String[] r = regra.split("->");
            if (r.length != 2) {
                throw new Exception("Regra mal formatada");
            }
            State estadoAtual = getStateByName(r[0]);
            if (estadoAtual == null) {
                throw new Exception("Regra mal formatada - Estado invalido1:" + r[0]);
            }
            try {
                for (String transicao : r[1].split("\\|")) {
                    State estadoDestino;
                    String letter = transicao.substring(0,1);
                    if(!checkLetter(letter)){
                        throw new Exception("Regra mal formata - Caracter invalido: " + transicao.substring(0,1));
                    }
                    if (transicao.substring(1).equals("")) {
                        estadoDestino = getStateByName("DEFAULT");
                    } else {
                        estadoDestino = getStateByName(transicao.substring(1));
                        if (estadoDestino == null) {
                            throw new Exception("Regra mal formatada - Estado invalido:" + transicao.substring(1));
                        }
                    }
                    this.rules.add(new Rule(letter, estadoAtual, estadoDestino));
                }
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                throw new Exception("Regra mal formatada");
            }
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<Rule> getPossibleRules(State estado, String elemento) {
        ArrayList<Rule> regras = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Rule r : this.rules) {
            if (r.getState() == estado && r.getElement().equals(elemento)) {
                regras.add(r);
            }
        }
        return regras;
    }

    public void setInicial(String inicial) throws Exception {
        State estado = getStateByName(inicial);
        if (estado == null) {
            throw new Exception("Estado inicial invalido");
        }
        this.inicial = estado;
    }

    // ({A,B,C}; {a,b,c}; A -> aB | bA | cA | λ, B -> aB | bC | cA | λ, C -> aB | bA | λ; A)
    public void readGrammar(String gramatica) throws Exception {
        gramatica = gramatica.replaceAll("\\(|\\)|\\s+|\\n", ""); // Tira parentesis e espaços

        if(gramatica.contains("=")){ // Tira o nome da gramatica do inicio
            gramatica = gramatica.split("=")[1];
        }
        gramatica = gramatica.replaceAll("\\},", "\\};"); // Substitui a , por ;
        String[] g = gramatica.split(";"); // Quebra partes da gramatica
        if (g.length != 4) {
            throw new Exception("Gramatica mal formatada");
        }
        setStates(g[0]);
        setAlphabet(g[1]);
        setRules(g[2]);
        setInicial(g[3]);
    }

  public void printRules() {
        for (Rule r : rules) {
            System.out.println(r.toString());
        }
    }

  boolean checkWord(String palavra) {
        System.out.format("%-10s %-10s\n", "Palavra", "Estado");
        System.out.format("%-10s %-10s\n", palavra, inicial);
        return checkWord(palavra, inicial);
    }

    boolean checkWord(String palavra, State estadoAtual) {
        System.out.format("%-10s %-10s\n", palavra, estadoAtual);
        if (palavra.isEmpty() && estadoAtual.getIsFinal()) { // terminou a palavra
            return true;
        } else if (palavra.isEmpty()) {
            return false;
        }
        ArrayList<Rule> possiveisRegras = getPossibleRules(estadoAtual, String.valueOf(palavra.charAt(0)));
        for (Rule r : possiveisRegras) {
            if (checkWord(palavra.substring(1), r.getDestiny())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Não tinha já feito esta pergunta ?

Comment: Já tinha feito para o mesmo programa, so que é para uma ação diferente agora :(